# Eliminate duplicate values (nodes) in data processed by nested for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, duplicates, nodes

I'm battling with a classic Dijkstra problem!

I've a set of nodes/cordinates. And I'm iterating over them to see if they're within a given `radius`.

```
x = np.empty([0, 3], dtype=float)
for j in range(len(Coord)):
    for k in range(len(Coord)):
        a = np.sqrt(((Coord[j][0] - Coord[k][0]) ** 2) + ((Coord[j][1] - Coord[k][1]) ** 2))
        if a < radius and a != 0:
            y = np.array([j, k, a])
            x = np.vstack((x, y))
```

Where `Coord` is an `array` of coordinates.

This gives me the values correctly, but as 0->3 is the same as 3->0 I get a lot of duplicate data. Which is the problem. The data should be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to begin the inner loop at the outer loop's position:

```
for j in range(len(Coord)):
    for k in range(j,len(Coord)):
       [loop body]
```

The high start in the `range` function will exclude all pairs of values where `j` is greater than `k`, preventing any duplicated without excluding any non-duplicated values.